# Google Maps MarkerClusterer show only one marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

My markers are generated from  xml parser. Its working and showing eg 7 markers, but when I added MC then it shows only 1 marker.
Check my js. 
Maybe it problem is here? `markers.push(marker);` ?

```
    function initialize() {
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(52.6145, 21.3418);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 6,
        center: chicago
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

    // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
    downloadUrl("db/parse_xml.php", function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
            var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
            var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
            var cover = markers[i].getAttribute("cover");
            var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
                parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
            var html = "<div id='infobox'><img src='" + cover + "'/><b>" + name + "</b><br>" + address + " <br/><input type='button' id='end' onClick=calcRoute() name='" + name + "," + address + "' value='Wyznacz trasę'></div>";
            var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: point,
                icon: icon.icon,
                shadow: icon.shadow
            });

            bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);

            document.getElementById('pasekBoczny').innerHTML += '<li class="list-sidebar" ><a href="javascript:myclick(' + i + ')"  >' + name + '</a></li>';
            markers.push(marker);
        }

        var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`markers` is a DOMNodeList, which doesn't have a method `push`

Create an array and populate the array with the `google.maps.Marker`'s

```
var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker"),
    markerArray=[];
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {

  /**
    * your code
    **/
  //markers.push(marker);<--error, remove it, currently the script will stop here
  markerArray.push(marker);//add this instead
}
var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markerArray);
```